# Map that is homotopic to the identity on $S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm looking for a homotopy that satisfies the following:

Let $B \subset S^n$ be an open ball around the north pole $N\in S^n$. There exists a homotopy $$ F : S^n \times I \to S^n$$
with $F(x,0) = x$ for all $x \in S^n$ and $g(x) = F(x,1)$ satisfies
$$g(B) = S^n - \{S\}, \ g(S^n - B) = \{S\}, \ g(N) = N, \ \text{g is smooth},$$ where $S$ is the south pole.

I have an idea of how $g$ should look like. I should kind of stretch the open ball $B$ onto all of $S^n - \{N\}$ if that makes sense. So points inside the ball $B$ should go towards the south pole on great circles between the north and south pole. But I have no idea how to write it down nicely and I'm also not sure how the homotopy should look like. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Is $B$ an open metric ball (with respect to the standard metric on $S^n$) or a space homeomorphic to the standard open ball in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @Tyrone Thank you for your comment. No, I messed up. I corrected it.

Comment: @PaulFrost It's $B_r(N) = \{ x \in S^n \ | \ ||x-N|| < r \}$ for some $r > 0$. I hope this makes sense. The metric $|| \ ||$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: Have you thought about using spherical coordinates?

Comment: @M.Wang Yes, that makes sense.